# unable to install libpng12-0 on kali

Tags: libpng, kali-linux

I am using the latest version of Kali.
I installed the Cisco Packet Tracer version 7.2. 
I ran it I got this error

> ./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now I am going to install **libpng12**

but I get this error

> (Reading database ... 485972 files and directories currently
>   installed.) Preparing to unpack libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
>   ... Unpacking libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.50-2+deb8u3) ... dpkg: error
>   processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb (--install): 
>   unable to install new version of
>   '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory
>   Errors were encountered while processing: 
>   libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb

I am using Debian sources list

> https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been through the same problem a solution I found was to :

1-Extract the content of the debian package 
`mkdir out; dpkg -x libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb  ./out`

2-Copy the file `libpng12.so.0` to your Packet tracer's installation directory inside the `.../pt/bin` folder like this:

`cp ./out/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 /opt/packettracer/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

i also had the same problem. I just installed it and strarted it up

```
packettracer
```

then it says

**Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.1**

but it doesnt start. 
and when I tried to run it from the opt/pt directory `./PacketTracer` it gives me

**./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

So what i did was download the libpng12.o.0 from source

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download

choose your architecture and mirror.Next go to the directory where the download is located.

```
cd Downloads
```

extract the package using

`dpkg -x libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb` .

open the lib directory

```
cd lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

list using

```
ls -alis
```

copy the libpng12.o.0 to where the packet tracer was saved if you installed it using default location using

```
cp libpng12.so.0 /opt/pt/bin/
```

type

```
cd
```

to move to home dir. Then type

```
packettracer
```

and you are good to go.

[kali-linux](/questions/tagged/kali-linux)[libpng12](/questions/tagged/libpng12)[libpng](/questions/tagged/libpng)[ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

after downloading the packettracer
open terminal ctrl+Alt+T

**step1**:  packettracer

It gives error like this

> ./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**step2**:so we want download [libpng12.so.0](http://%20https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libpng12-0/download)

**step3**:choose  which you want and download it

**example**:[http.us.debian.org/debian](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb)

**step4**:go to the downloads folder right click on **.deb** file and run it as software installation

**step5**:open terminal ctrl+Alt+T  type

```
packettracer
```

starting packettracer